# Tile filter for libav/avconv

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, avconv

Is there some way to use libav/avconv to duplicate the effect of the tile filter in FFMPEG?

I'm trying to create a strip of images from left to right with one image for every ten seconds of video input.

My plan is to first generate the images and then create the image strip. Preferably I want to use libav over ffmpeg. So far I have created this:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1,fps=1/10 -q:v 6 img%03d.jpg
```

which creates the images. But then I only know how create the image with ffmpeg using:

```
ffmpeg -i img%03d.jpg -filter_complex tile=6x1 output.jpg
```

So if anyone has any tips on how to rewrite the just the second or both commands to use avconv I welcome any advise :)

Comment: Why do you not want to use `ffmpeg` instead?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The server running it is using a Google Cloud App Engine docker image which I believe is based on Ubunto 14.XX and does not ship with ffmpeg. So using avconv saves me setting up full manual download in the dockerfile

Comment: Is it not possible to use a [static build](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard sure. I just hoped to avoid it. I'm not that good at creating docker files and find installing binaries from static builds kinda messy and time consuming

Comment: `avconv` is missing many features present in `ffmpeg` including the tile filter (and hundreds of others). A sloppy, monotonous solution would be to use the color source filter as a background and one overlay filter per image to manually place each image. Or use a different tool such as `montage` from imagemagick if that's available in your docker stuff.

Comment: I ended up getting a static build of `ffmpeg`. Thanks for your answers @LordNeckbeard

Comment: You can add that as an answer since you found an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As libav/avconv did not have any filters supporting my requirements in any easy way switching to a static build of `ffmpeg` was the simplest solution.

The commands then became:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1,fps=1/10 -q:v 6 img%03d.jpg
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i img%03d.jpg -filter_complex tile=6x1 output.jpg
```